Removing commits from branch
I want to create new branch from my main.
I have about 50 pushed commits (it's not last 50 commits in branch, they're mixed with others commits) in my main branch that shouldn't be in the newly created branch.
do you know how to achieve this?
I read about interactive rebase, but this option is disabled in my git:log in intelij. There's any other option? There's maybe option to squash some existing commits?

Why not doing it from the command line outside of you ide?

If it's the top 50 you don't want, reset your new branch to the commit you want it to point to. If the 50 you don't want are mixed in throughout, then use interactive rebase. However, typically main is a shared branch that is a source of truth for other branches. Not sure what you're planning to do by deviating so much from main?

"50 pushed commits"? Why do you call them "pushed" here? Are other commits in your main branch somehow "unpushed"? Everything in your question seems to be local. Please clarify.

This question is similar to: Git: How to create a branch from an older version, and selectively add commits since then. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yes, my 50 commits - it's mixed in my branch, that's not last 50 commits. I'll try with interactive rebase

Is the branch ever going to be merged back into main? If so, should those commits also be removed from main at that point? You should treat commits as permanent "members" of any branch, which is not to say that later commits (such as those created by git revert) cannot "undo" changes made by previous commits.
